# FileReader not reading file properly

Tags: javascript, filereader

I ran the following function with a valid file object but it didn't work. The read text was an empty string. However, when I run the same commands via the console, it does work.

```
function(file) {
  console.log(file)
  var reader = new FileReader();
  reader.readAsText(file);
  console.log(reader.readyState);
  console.log(reader.result);
}
```

Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I needed to set a callback for when the reader finishes reading the file, as this is done asynchronously.

```
function(file) {
  console.log(file)
  var reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = function() {
    console.log(reader.readyState);
    console.log(reader.result);
  }
  reader.readAsText(file);
}
```

Comment: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/

Comment: Hahahaha fair enough. :D. But these type of question already been answered here.

Comment: :)
It took me a while to figure it out despite searching. So thought it might be helpful.